# Python shapely Polygon.contains(Point) not giving correct answer (I think)

Tags: python, shapely

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

p = Point(2,2)
poly = Polygon((0,0), (0,5), (5,0), (5,5))

print poly.contains(p)
```

This prints `False`, although I'm pretty sure `(2,2)` is within a square of length `5`. Or maybe I just don't know how the contains method really works. `p.within(poly)` also return `False`. Am I using the `Polygon` class correctly or am I just really bad at geometry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the polygon should be constructed as

```
Polygon([(0,0), (5,0), (5,5), (0,5)])
```

in your case, the sequence `(0,0), (0,5), (5,0), (5,5)` specifies a "letter Z" rotated 90 degrees clockwise, not a boundary of the square of interest. As it is, it wouldn't even yield a valid polygon, i.e.

```
>>> P=Polygon([(0,0), (0,5), (5,0), (5,5)])
>>> P.area
0.0
>>> P.is_valid
Self-intersection at or near point 2.5 2.5
False
```